# Measuring Active power through current sensors

Tags: microcontroller, power, current-measurement, energy

i want to measure the AC current - with 220 V AC 50 HZ at home -
i will use a current sensor then find the power factor through comparing the signals of the V and I then find the power then i integrate to find the Energy consumed by using micron controller.

My Questions

1- What are the considerations for the current sensor?

2- do they produce an AC voltage exactly proportional to the waveform of the current? i watched the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7XIXOHnmOSo) , i think the answer is yes?

3- can you recommend some as the only i found are from here [1](http://www.allegromicro.com/en/Products/Current-Sensor-ICs/Zero-To-Fifty-Amp-Integrated-Conductor-Sensor-ICs.aspx), i don't know if they are are reliable or not?

4- is the total algorithm right or there are problems?
Thanks.

Comment: "Find the power factor through comparing the signals of the V and I" may not be so easy.  For purely reactive or power factor corrected loads you might have a shot at that but for highly non-linear loads (e.g. bridge rectified supplies w/o PFC) the harmonic distortion in the current will make a simple comparison between voltage and current difficult and you will have to resort to more advanced DSP techniques.

Comment: Have a look at the open source hardware and software energy meter project at http://openenergymonitor.org to learn about this subject. They have it all worked out and by studying the articles you will learn many of the design features required to do energy measurement successfully. Your question 3 is a shopping question and these are disallowed on EE.SE. See the Help Center.

Answer (score 3):

> find the power factor through comparing the signals of the V and I

Hmmm...

> is the total algorithm right or there are problems?

Finding power factor by comparing V and I waveforms is really problematic. Consider the load taken by a typical electronic appliance: -

[image]

This is the sort of current shape taken by a bridge rectifier when connected to a reservoir capacitor and load. Cutrrent only passes as the capacitor gets "topped-up" with charge. Using some form of zero cross measurement strategy will not work because of the highly distorted waveform.

If you want to measure power, instantaneously multiply v and i samples then average - this will give you real power into the appliance. But also you need to oversample the fundamental frequency of your AC by a good amount to account the for at least the ninth harmonic. A half decent power measurement device might sample at 1 kHz and sample both v and i simultaneously.

> What are the considerations for the current sensor?

A current transformer (CT) is pretty normal. Hall effect sensors too. No specific recommendations.

> do they produce an AC voltage exactly proportional to the waveform of
>   the current?

CT's do when used with the correct burden resistor but, as always, the data in the specific data sheet will always give a better idea.